# How to allow sorting by foreign key fields?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

Consider the following django-tables2 table:

```
class ProductMaxIPPortEldCountTable(tables.Table):                             
    vendor = tables.TemplateColumn('{{ record.product.vendor }}')
```

When I try to sort it by `vendor`, which is a foreign key in the underlying model, I get "Cannot resolve keyword u'vendor' into field." error. How can I give django-tables2 a hint on how this column is linked to a model field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `Column` with an `accessor` helped:

```
class ProductMaxIPPortEldCountTable(tables.Table):                          
    vendor = tables.Column(accessor='product.vendor')
```